# Get values of tds in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok how you can see in my fiddle im trying to manipulate the left table, so that at the end it looks like the table on the right: http://jsfiddle.net/SULK3/2/

To do this i first try to get the values of the `td`s  loop through them and look for the dates and change the rowspans upon the data i get: So i started with a normal table and this code:

```
var values = [];
   var table = $(this).closest("table");
   table.find("tr").each(function() {
      values.push($(this).find("td:first").html());
   });

$('#values').text(values);
```

But somehow it wont work, the values of the rows wont be outgiven in the div with the id values! Why? (If you have ideas how to solve my 'big'-problem please post it also here!) Thanks

Comment: I think we need more information about what your trying to do and why..  Based on `im trying to manipulate the left table, so that at the end it looks like the table on the right` You can just take the html from the table on the right and insert that html into the table on the left.. Why are you posting the values into `#values`?  http://jsfiddle.net/SULK3/5/

Comment: Thanks that you are trying to help me! My problem is this, i have a table and how you can see there a several rows with the same day! Now it would be more clearer for the reader if the day is only dislpayed once for several rows! So i try to maipulate the rowspan! I hope yo understood me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably going to try to accomplish this with the array you are building.  And just wanted to know why the values were not showing up in `#values`.

I wasn't sure so I started working on a solution.. I came back to see you had already marked an accepted answer which is great that must have been what you were looking for.

I don't expect or want you to mark this as the accepted answer but I had fun trying to find a solution, so here you go:

```
var dateCount = 0;
var addtoTr = 0;
var table = $("table:first");
var date = table.find('tr:first').find('td:first').html();

   table.find("tr").each(function(index) {
       if(date === $(this).find("td:first").html() || date === ''){
        dateCount++;
       }
       else{
          table.find('tr').eq(addtoTr).prepend('<td rowspan='+dateCount+'>'+date+'</td>');
          dateCount = 1;
          date = $(this).find("td:first").html();
          addtoTr = index;
       } 
       $(this).find("td:first").remove();
   });
   table.find('tr').eq(addtoTr).prepend('<td rowspan='+dateCount+'>'+date+'</td>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SULK3/6/

This is only one way to do it.. I'm sure there are many other, and better ways.

Comment: Thanks its excellent code! Couldnt do it better myself! I only have on litte issue i tried to add an `<thead>` an that distrubs the code a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/SULK3/9/ ! The thing is the code should only select the `<tr>` in the `<tbody>`! So i tried to modify yo code with `closets('tbody').find('tr')` but that somehow didnt worked! Could you please revise your code? Thanks so much!

Comment: Ok finally solved it myself! http://jsfiddle.net/SULK3/10/ I simply changed the `table:first` to `tbody:first` but thanks again! and have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
var table = $(this).closest("table");
```

what is `this`? In the fiddle, it's the window, which has no closest table, as closest() means closest parent element?

As there <s>is only one table</s>, are two tables, just changing it to

```
var table = $('table:first')
```

seems to work :

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/SULK3/4/)

Comment: actually there are 2 tables in the html.

Comment: so `var table = $('table:first')`

Comment: My eyesight must be going, there are of course two tables, and yes, `$('table:first')` would work, the answer is still basically the same, trying to use `this` in a scope that makes no sense and where there is no closest table won't work!

Comment: No surprise, adeneo. With all the correct answers you've provided in the last few months it's a wonder you're not cross-eyed.